# android flush sqlite table

Tags: android, sqlite, flush

what is the best way to flush or empty an android sqlite table and delete every thing in it...??? and if i upgrade the database VERSION will it flush the table

this is how i delete one item but i want to delete all rows (i dont know how many rows i have) to empty the table

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

        //---delete a title---
        db.open();
        if (db.deleteTitle(1))
            Toast.makeText(this, "Delete successful.", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(this, "Delete failed.", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
        db.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
```

or

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "1", null);
```

From the documentation of SQLiteDatabase [delete](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) method:

> To remove all rows and get a count pass "1" as the whereClause.

Answer (score 1):

It's an sql database, just do `DELETE * FROM yourtable`, which nukes all rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can just execute the SQL query: `db.execSQL("DELETE FROM <table-name>;");`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to delete all of the app's data, you can use the 'Clear Data' button found in Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> 'your app'.

Comment: But what if you want to do so programmatically, and only flush some (not all) tables?